# how to check whether a string starts with xx and ends with yy in shellscript?

Tags: shell, unix, less-unix

In the below example I want to find whether the sentence starts with 'ap' and ends with 'e'.

> example: a="apple"

```
if [[ "$a" == ^"ap"+$ ]]
```

This is not giving proper output.

Comment: suggest adding a tag for you specific shell, maybe `bash` or `ksh`

Comment: What's with the less-unix tag?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which shell you're using, but the `[[` in your attempt suggests you're using one that expands upon the base POSIX sh language. The following works with at least `bash`, `zsh` and `ksh93`:

```
$ a=apple
$ [[ $a == ap*e ]] && echo matches # Wildcard pattern
matches
$ [[ $a =~ ^ap.*e$ ]] && echo matches # Regular expression - note the =~
matches
```